# Implementing trait methods for specific types

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to create a Coder trait with two methods (encode and decode). Each implementation of the trait needs to deal only with a specific type of input/output, so for instance:

- BytesCoder should only receive &[u8] as inputs to encode and should only generate &[u8] as decoded outputs.
- KVCoder should only receive HashMaps as inputs to encode and should only generate HashMaps as decoded outputs.

**Approach 1:** a simple way to satisfy the compiler would be to make encode and decode accept Any, and have each implementation deal with it separately. This seems like a bad idea since each coder should only deal with a single type.

```
type SomeEncodableHopefully = Box<dyn std::any::Any>;

pub trait Coder {
    fn encode(&self, element: SomeEncodableHopefully) -> &[u8];

    fn decode(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> SomeEncodableHopefully;
}

pub struct BytesCoder {
    ...
}

impl BytesCoder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ...
    }
}

impl Coder for BytesCoder {]
    // "element" should only be &[u8] instead of Any
    fn encode(&self, element: SomeEncodableHopefully) -> &[u8] {
        ...
    }

    // The output shouldn't be Any either
    fn decode(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> SomeEncodableHopefully {
        ...
    }
}

pub struct KVCoder {
    ...
}

impl KVCoder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ...
    }
}

impl Coder for KVCoder {]
    // "element" should only be HashMap<...> instead of Any
    fn encode(&self, element: SomeEncodableHopefully) -> &[u8] {
        ...
    }

    // The output shouldn't be Any either
    fn decode(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> SomeEncodableHopefully {
        ...
    }
}

fn test_coder(coder: Box<dyn Coder>, to_encode: SomeEncodableHopefully, to_decode: &[u8]) {
    let encoded:&[u8] = coder.encode(to_encode);
    let decoded:SomeEncodableHopefully = coder.decode(to_decode);
}
```

**Approach 2:** I tried to use an associated type, but I wasn't able to succesfully define a fixed type for each implementation of Coder:

```
pub trait Coder {
    // The compiler ignores Element on each implementation and requires
    // this to be defined manually when a coder is used
    type Element;

    fn encode(&self, element: Self::Element) -> &[u8];

    fn decode(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Self::Element;
}

...

impl Coder for BytesCoder {
    // This gets ignored
    type Element = &[u8];

    fn encode(&self, element: Self::Element) -> &[u8] {
        ...
    }

    fn decode(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Self::Element {
        ...
    }
}

...

// Error on coder: the value of the associated type `Element` (from trait `Coder`) must be specified
fn test_coder(coder: Box<dyn Coder>, to_encode: SomeEncodableHopefully, to_decode: &[u8]) {
    let encoded:&[u8] = coder.encode(to_encode);
    let decoded:SomeEncodableHopefully = coder.decode(to_decode);
}
```

**Approach 3:** it could be a good idea to define type-specific versions of encode and decode. I had no complaints from the compiler, but this would be pretty verbose if there are many types involved (including, for instance: HashMap<A,B>, HashMap<A,C>, ...):

```
pub trait Coder {
    fn encode_to_bytes(&self, element: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        panic!("Invalid operation for this type of coder");
    }

    fn decode_to_bytes(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        panic!("Invalid operation for this type of coder");
    }

    fn encode_to_some_other_type (&self, element: SomeOtherType) -> &[u8] {
        panic!("Invalid operation for this type of coder");        
    }

    fn decode_to_some_other_type (&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> SomeOtherType {
        panic!("Invalid operation for this type of coder");        
    }

}

...

// Ok
impl Coder for BytesCoder {
    fn encode_to_bytes(&self, element: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        ...
    }

    fn decode_to_bytes(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        ...
    }
}

...
```

The third approach seems to solve the problem somewhat decently, but is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Given that `&[u8]` is a reference and not an owning type, who would own the returned value? Are you going to modify the contents of your byte array in-place?

Comment: I'd usually go with an associated type and an adapter type with `Box<dyn Any>`. But the fact that the types aren't `'static` makes that impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error of your second approach requests you to specify the type of `Coder` it has to match with the type of `to_encode` for this to work. I introduce a generic here to make it as flexible as possible.

```rust
fn test_coder<E>(coder: Box<dyn Coder<Element = E>>, to_encode: E, to_decode: &[u8]) {
    let encoded: &[u8] = coder.encode(to_encode);
    let decoded: E = coder.decode(to_decode);
}
```

Which leaves open the question of who owns your slices that SirDarius raised.
You probably should return an owned type instead since generally you can't take a `&[u8]` from every type:

```rust
pub trait Coder {
    type Element;

    fn encode(&self, element: Self::Element) -> Vec<u8>;
    fn decode(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Self::Element;
}

struct BytesCoder;
type SomeEncodableHopefully = Vec<u8>;
impl Coder for BytesCoder {
    type Element = Vec<u8>;

    fn encode(&self, element: Self::Element) -> Vec<u8> {
        element
    }

    fn decode(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Self::Element {
        bytes.to_vec()
    }
}
```

If `Element` has to be a reference you can use a GAT in it's stead. Or make the trait take a lifetime.

Comment: This signature for test_coder certainly works but not for every use case I had in mind, since you have to know the type beforehand dynamically. 
Is there truly no way to set a default type for each trait implementation? 
For instance, if "coder" is a BytesCoder, it should ideally be implicit that E = Vec<u8>, and the E wouldn't be necessary since the coder shouldn't accept any other type.

Comment: It is implicit for a `BytesCoder` just not for a `dyn Coder` which can be any type that implements `Coder`.